# Returning the first result

Tags: swift, xcode, request, coreml, apple-vision

I'm new to swift and trying my best to learn as much as possible and searching through many forums. However, the answer to this question doesn't appear to be anywhere. So I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with this.

I'm wanting to return the first value that the Model things the image might be. It returns one most of the time but when unsure it provides maybe two or three. Even though I have specified the first command within the request.results?.first part of the method.

I'm using a text back to display the results self.Output.text = "Item: (classification!.identifier.capitalized)"

I have tried playing with the syntax to include first but no luck. I tried thinking about this as an array but I don't believe there would be one as the data is only returned after the image is taken.

```
func detect(image: CIImage) {

    // Load the ML model through its generated class
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model) else {
        fatalError("can't load ML model")
    }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        let classification = request.results?.first as? VNClassificationObservation

        self.Output.text = "Item: \(classification!.identifier.capitalized)"

        }


    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

    do {
        try handler.perform([request])

    }
    catch {
        print(error)

    }

}
```

I'm getting results I just need to narrow this down to one.

Comment: What do you mean by "when unsure it provides maybe two or three"? The code you'd provided always gets the first result only, so the issue might be somewhere else in your code. (Also, you should create the `VNCoreMLModel` just once, but every time you want to classify an image.)

Comment: Can you print `request.results`, as it would be useful to see the structure of this.

Comment: Hi Both, so I have posted an example link below to an image of the app front end which shows the results - I just want it to return one value but as shown below it returns two. It doesn't always do this but this isn't the first value? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjfCnEN_Gb0rhLhTzUIW7s8rKVLelw?e=3jlgIC

For the results show in the log some of it is shown here:

0E1C6 requestRevision=1 confidence=0.000199 "printer", <VNClassificationObservation: 0x2832c28e0> 798F8A17-7D17-469F-A305-8FE1B2A7A764 requestRevision=1 confidence=0.000199 "sea cucumber, holothurian", <VNClassificationObservation

Comment: Only had enough characters to share some of the log.